# Как разбить объект на части?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть объект типа - `const lol = { z: 3, a: 4, b: 1, c: 6}`

Как из него получить массив объектов типа - `qwe = [{z: 3},{a: 4},{b: 1},{c: 6}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функциональное решение, используются:

- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- метод [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) для массивов
- [Вычисление имён свойств](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_ECMAScript_2015) в записи объекта
- Синтаксис `() => ({ключ: значение})` для возврата объекта из лямбды

```js
const object = { z: 3, a: 4, b: 1, c: 6};
const result = Object
  .entries(object)
  .map(entry => ({[entry[0]]: entry[1]}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const lol = { z: 3, a: 4, b: 1, c: 6};

function toArr(obj)
{
  const res = [];
  for (let key in obj)
  {
    let buf = {};
    buf[key] = obj[key];
    res.push(buf);
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(toArr(lol));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const lol = {
  z: 3,
  a: 4,
  b: 1,
  c: 6
};
const a = [];
for (i in lol) {
  var o = new Object();
  o[i] = lol[i];
  a.push(o)
}

console.log(a)
```